# rendering html as plaintext without stripping whitespace

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, whitespace

Basically I am pulling an HTML file from a server and displaying the source code in the browser, including the tags.  Currently, i pull the file down as a stream and convert it to a string:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(item.DownloadFile());
string raw = reader.ReadToEnd();
file.Contents = raw;
```

And then

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(file.Contents);
```

which is displayed in my view using

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Contents)
```

This works fine for displaying all of the source. HOWEVER the output is a single block of text, completely stripped of whitespace, and thus is not easily readable, which defeats the purpose of me displaying the source code.

How can i output the source code such that indentation and newlines remain in tact?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to HTML encode the content and then use `@Html.Raw` to unencode it. The purpose of `@Html.Raw` is to actually render the HTML, Razor will, by default, HTML encode any HTML-style content, so you can just do `@Model.Contents` (without ever calling `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`) and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either wrap your code in

```
<pre> 
    @Html.Raw(Model.Contents)
</pre>
```

Or using CSS, add the following rule:

```
whitespace:pre;
```